# Prevent users from submitting a form with a certain string

Tags: php, forms

Normally my form prevented users to submit it when it was under 4 characters. I want to add a second condition that prevents them from submitting the form when they are submitting the string "Buscá tu ciudad". I tried added the condition below but it didn't work.

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s').value.length < 4) return false;" style="float:right; display:inline; padding-right:10px;">

<input class="ubicacion" name="s" id="s" tabindex="1" onsubmit="if ((document.getElementById('s').value.length < 4) || (document.getElementById('s')== 'Cambiá de ciudad')) return false;" onfocus="if (this.value=='Cambiá de ciudad') this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Cambiá de ciudad'" type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="Cambiá de ciudad" style="width:198px; color:grey;">

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" />
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please validate input on server side and sanitize user input too. `strlen($_GET['s']) < 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there even an `onsubmit` available on an `input` element?  Even if there is, for consistency I'd think you'd want to put all of the logic in the `onsubmit` for the `form` element (as you started to do).

A few other things to note:

1. You should separate your markup from your code.  By mixing the two, things like this become a lot less obvious and a lot harder to support.
2. Client-side validation is more of a convenience to the user than anything else.  Even with this working correctly, if you ask, "Why is it not preventing users from submitting something incorrect?" then the first answer would be, "Are you checking on the server-side?  If not then you're allowing the users to submit anything they want."

Answer (score 1):

You should add event listeners, not like this. Second thing you need is to check input on server side, if someone disables JavaScript all of this is pointless.

```
$s = htmlspecialchars($_POST["s"], ENT_QUOTES);

if(strlen($s) < 4 || $s == "Buscá tu ciudad"){
 $error[] = "something";
}
```

For JS you can use jQuery, write less do more.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can't use onsubmit on an input, only on the form itself. also, this isn't a php question, this should be tagged javascript

Comment: Thanks, that was my first mistake, I tried this on the form but it doesn't work:

 <form role="search" method="get" action="chusmix.com/"; onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s')== 'Cambiá de ciudad") return false;'>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that to your forms `onSubmit`, not the textbox.

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s').value.length < 4 || document.getElementById('s') == 'Cambiá de ciudad') return false;" style="float:right; display:inline; padding-right:10px;">
```

And yes, perform on the server-side as well.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why? 
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s')== 'Cambiá de ciudad") return false;'>